# Why does this function's results show up as NaN?

Tags: javascript, input, web

I have this simple piece of code:

```js
var numb1 = document.getElementById("numb1")
var numb2 = document.getElementById("numb2")
var numb3 = document.getElementById("numb3")
var numb4 = document.getElementById("numb4")
var v1 = parseInt(numb1)
var v2 = parseInt(numb2)
var v3 = parseInt(numb3)
var v4 = parseInt(numb4)
var t = parseInt(0)

function myFunction() {
  if (numb1.checked == true) {
    var t = v1 + t
  } else if (numb2.checked == true) {
    var t = v2 + t
  } else if (numb3.checked == true) {
    var t = v3 + t
  } else if (numb4.checked == true) {
    var t = v4 + t
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = t
}
```

```html
<input id="numb1" type="radio" value="10">
<input id="numb2" type="radio" value="50">
<input id="numb3" type="radio" value="80">
<input id="numb4" type="radio" value="120">

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

I get that I definitely could have been more efficient when making my variables, but my problem is that even after I use `parseInt()` to go from string to integer, the end result in `demo` displays `NaN`. Is there something wrong with the way I defined the variables, or is it the calculation of the end value?

Comment: Use `console.log()` to debug these sorts of problems. You don't need to be in the dark on what the values of your variables are. There are many tools built right into your browser that will tell you what you need to know about your code.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: You're welcome. You'll find that getting familiar with at least the basics of the debugging tools will make coding much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `parseInt( elementObject )` doesn't return a valid number.

You wanted to parse the value, with a radix

```
var v1 = parseInt(numb1.value, 10);
```

And you have to get those values **inside** the function, when the value has actually changed.

Also, add some semicolons, they aren't always needed, but it's good practice to add them, and don't redeclare variables

```js
var numb1 = document.getElementById("numb1");
var numb2 = document.getElementById("numb2");
var numb3 = document.getElementById("numb3");
var numb4 = document.getElementById("numb4");


function myFunction() {
    var v1 = parseInt(numb1.value, 10);
    var v2 = parseInt(numb2.value, 10);
    var v3 = parseInt(numb3.value, 10);
    var v4 = parseInt(numb4.value, 10);
    var t = 0;

    if (numb1.checked) {
        t = v1 + t;
    } else if (numb2.checked) {
        t = v2 + t;
    } else if (numb3.checked) {
        t = v3 + t;
    } else if (numb4.checked) {
        t = v4 + t;
    }
    
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = t
}
```

```html
<input id="numb1" type="radio" value="10">
<input id="numb2" type="radio" value="50">
<input id="numb3" type="radio" value="80">
<input id="numb4" type="radio" value="120">

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: There's a "snippet" in the answer, showing it working. It's hard to answer why it doesn't work for you, when it works here ?

Comment: Sorry I think I read your answer before it was finished. It's working now

Comment: Also, would you mind explaining to me why it doesn't function properly when variable t is out of the function?

Comment: It probably works with `t` declared outside the function, but all the `numb1.value` etc has to be inside the function, because the values has to be read when the function runs, otherwise those values are only read on pageload, and never change.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the answer by adeneo. The issue is that you are `parseInt`ing an  HTML Input Element.

And you already got the answer.

But I noticed that you use `if..else`

So, You want only one value to be selected by the user.

So, There is a short method which also help to improve the loading speed and reduce lines of codes.

using `forms`

```js
function myFunction(){
    t=parseInt(document.forms[0]["num"].value);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=t
}
```

```html
<form>
<input id="numb1" name="num" type="radio" value="10">
<input id="numb2" name="num" type="radio" value="50">
<input id="numb3" name="num" type="radio" value="80">
<input id="numb4" name="num" type="radio" value="120">

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>
</form>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: I will definitely look into using forms more often. Thanks